# How to check all class have been tested in Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

I'm using Gradle with jacoco plugin and I'm looking a way to check all classes of the project were tested in unit test and at least the half of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found

```
// apply plugin
apply "jacoco"

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        violationRules {
            rule {
                // this rule insure 50% of instructions have been tested 
                limit {
                    minimum = 0.5
                }
            }
            rule {
                // this rule insure all classes have been tested
                limit {
                    counter = 'CLASS'
                    value = 'MISSEDCOUNT'
                    maximum = 0                 
                }
            }       
        }
}
```